# Не удается найти главный класс

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

Есть задание создать апплет-клавиатуру.

Создавал проект в NetBeans IDE 8.1  так:
<kbd>Создать проект</kbd> → <kbd>Java</kbd> → <kbd>Приложение Java</kbd> → <kbd>Имя проекта (AppletKeybboard)</kbd>

После создания в пакетах исходных кодов → <kbd>другие</kbd> → <kbd>формы Swing GUI</kbd> →
<kbd>Форма JApplet</kbd>. Название файла Keyboard.
Проблема возникла при компиляции. Пишет "не удается найти главный класс".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Апплеты это не приложение Java, а библиотека. Создайте проект "Библиотека классов Java". Библиотека не требует наличия главного класса.

[Не забываем про первоисточники](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets_ru.html)

Если без главного метода совсем никак, то просто добавьте к любому из своих классов метод `static void main(String[] args)`, или создайте новый класс

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Запускать он ничего не будет, но ошибку компиляции должен снять.

Comment: не помагает, сразу так и делал

Comment: а то, что в вопросе -  вторая попытка (нашел в инете  этот способ)

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: не помогает. Сообственно говоря, надо написать апплет клавиатуру с использованием формочек. Раньше похожие задания делал и подобных проблем не было